# Vim Error "An error occurred while processing function ~AND" "E716: Key not present in Dictionary~" Solution

Tags: go, vim, vim-plugin

■Error Description.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>35_debounceTimeTimerCallback[1]..
<SNR>35_tapSourceCallback[4]..<SNR>35_tapSourceCallback[1]..<lambda>30[1]..<SNR
>55_set_signs[10]..<SNR>55_place_signs:
line    5:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: linecount + 1
```

■Cause of error content output
I have set up an environment for Go development using the Vim editor on VirtusalBox.

■Contents of .vimrc

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-settings'
call plug#end()
```

I am unsure of the solution, can you please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

You can see a list of the files that have been sourced by Vim with `:help :scriptnames`:

```
:scr
```

The `XX` in all the `<SNR>XX`s in the stack trace refers to script number `XX` in the output of the command above.

For example, this is the output of `:scr` in `$ vim --clean` on my machine:

```
  1: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/defaults.vim
  2: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
  3: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
  4: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim
  5: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  6: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
  7: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

If I get a stack trace mentioning `<SNR>4`, I know the problem is in the `~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim` file that comes with Vim. In this fictitious case, I would probably debug it a little bit further and open an issue on Vim's issue tracker.

In your case, the problem is very likely to happen in one of your plugins. Once you have identified it, you should head off to its issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you!
The output seems to have been generated by the introduction of vim-lsp.
It looks like the following file, but I will try to find the fix again.
I have only installed the vim editor for a few days, so I have a lot of unknowns...
Thanks so much for helping me grow!!!

35: ~/.vim/plugged/vim-lsp/autoload/lsp/callbag.vim
55: ~/.vim/plugged/vim-lsp/autoload/lsp/internal/diagnostics/signs.vim

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug of vim-lsp.

This [pull request](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp/pull/1360) was merged to master 3 days ago. Removing the following lines from **~/.vim/plugged/vim-lsp/autoload/lsp/internal/diagnostics/signs.vim** worked for me.

```
" Some language servers report an unexpected EOF one line past the end
if l:line == getbufinfo(a:bufnr)[0].linecount + 1
    let l:line = l:line - 1
endif
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to confirm that there is no output successfully.